# Possible to hide/display a feed in an email campaign using Mailchimp's merge tags?

Tags: email, mailchimp

I'm setting up a mailchimp newsletter template that's fed with a couple RSS feeds. My goal is to hide a feed's section when the RSS feed does not have any items. I imagine it could work something like:

```
*|FEEDBLOCK:feed_url|*

*|IF:FEEDITEMS|*
    *|FEEDITEMS|*
        <!-- Display Items -->
    *|END:FEEDITEMS|*
*|END:IF|*

*|END:FEEDBLOCK|*
```

But I'm not having any luck. I've looked through Mailchimp's docs, but haven't found an answer. Am I approaching this the wrong way?